# why close() method be synchronized while extending RecordReader in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I would looking at example given alexhomes's hadoop-book [here](https://github.com/alexholmes/hadoop-book/blob/master/src/main/java/com/manning/hip/ch3/json/JsonInputFormat.java)

I could not understand why close method is synchronized? and why only close() and no other method ?

```
public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
  reader.close();
}
```

Can some one explain me? That will be very helpful.

Comment: well ask him why he made that synchronized, the interfaces don't force you to declare the method synchronized.

Comment: And unless you're running the multi threaded-mapper (generally discouraged), it's all single threaded anyway. Even then, MultithreadedMapper has it's own sync around the record reader anyway (See the source for `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.MultithreadedMapper.SubMapRecordReader.nextKeyValue()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mention in the book, I used the [ElephantBird](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird) project's [LzoJsonRecordReader](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/mapreduce/input/LzoJsonRecordReader.java) class as a basis for my version, as I wanted to write one which didn't require LZOP compression. ElephantBird used a synchronized close method in their RecordReader, which as a result made its way into my version too. As other have mentioned there is no reason that I know of to synchronize the close method in MapReduce.